# SonarQube rule "common-java:DuplicatedBlocks" on import statements

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I have a problem with the rule "common-java:DuplicatedBlocks" for sonarQube 4.5 with java plugin 3.3

```
import static com.something.mystuf.Constants.GREEN;
import static com.something.mystuf.Constants.RED;
```

gives a violation on the rule. But i do not want to write

```
import static com.something.mystuf.Constants.*;
```

if i only use two colors of the possible hundreds. Shouldn't the rule ignore imports? There already is a duplicated imports rule i assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if we can configure the rule to ignore duplicate blocks on imports ... (i don't think so).

But SonarQube is a tool to help to write better code and you should not always follow the rules. It is possible to mark violations as false positives. 
And I think that's what you must do in this case.

OR, you should not use static imports. The code will be more readable and maintainable without static imports.

Comment: I disagree with the static imports part. When i see GREEN or RED in the code it is perfectly clear. The Constants in front of it is just noise IMO.

Comment: We are not agree on static imports and I respect your opinion. This is a controversial debate, there people for and people against and we will not discuss here. Free to you to use them or not.
But  if you do not want to report false positives or disable the rule, this is a solution to avoid the violation of this rule ....

Comment: Which results in a lot of false positives for all classes that perform some argument validation. 
'import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;' 
Unfortunate. But ok.